# How to display customer name instead of My Account in header

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, theme

I would like to display the customer name when they are logged in. I know that I have to use something like the below code but I don't know how to implement it.

```
<?php if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){ ?>
    <span class="top-link-myaccount"><?php echo $this->__('Account'); ?></span>
    <?php }else{ ?>
    <span class="top-link-myaccount"><?php echo 'Hi, '.Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getFirstname(); ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

My customer xml and header files are as follow:

customer.xml

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position><li/><a>class="top-link-myaccount"</a></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

header.phtml

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks');
```

top.links.phtml

```
<?php if($toplinks && is_array($toplinks)): ?>
<ul class="links">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
    <?php foreach($toplinks as $_toplink): ?>
    <li<?php if($_toplink['first']||$_toplink['last']): ?> class="<?php if($_toplink['first']): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if($_toplink['last']): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_toplink['liParams'] ?>><?php echo $_toplink['beforeText'] ?><a <?php echo $_toplink['aParams'] ?>><?php echo $_toplink['innerText'] ?></a><?php echo $_toplink['afterText'] ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the label for logged-in customer from layout file ... in your `customer.xml` within

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
```

add this

```
<action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/></action>
<action method="addLink" translate="title" module="customer"><label helper="customer/getCustomerName"/><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
```

This will remove the `<default>` "My Account" link first and then add a new link that calls `Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::getCustomerName` to show the customers name instead of "My Account".

If you need custom text add your own helper that returns the text you need.

Comment: I added your code to the `<customer_logged_in>` code block that I had for "Log in" but it doesn't work. I also created a separate code block as `<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
  <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/></action>
  <action method="addLink" translate="title" module="customer"><label helper="customer/getCustomerName"/><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
 </reference>
</customer_logged_in>` but it doesn't work as well. am I missing something?

Comment: @R.Toward Have you flushed cache? Tested it before posting ... so what happens if you  add that code? (can you try to remove the link - w/o readding ... just to see if this works?)

Comment: The problem was because of my login form, it works fine now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can check below screenshot for your requirement

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2728589/90333095ca4f62a4ae53f32300b1b88f

You have add these code in your

File path:app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/account/navigation.phtml

```
<?php $CustomerName = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getFirstname();?>
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__($CustomerName); ?></span></strong>
```

Comment: I need to change in the header not like the one in your screenshot. You didn't get my question.